# What statistical tests to compare two AUCs from two models on the same dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

Let say I build two machine learning classifiers, A and B, on the same dataset.

I obtain the ROC curves for both A and B, and the AUCs value.

What statistical tests should I use to compare these two classifiers. (Let say A is the one I innovate, and B is a baseline model).

Thanks!

Comment: ROC AUC is a Mann-Whitney U statistic, so those confidence intervals are directly relevant here. More discussion in the answers to and comments on this thread: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/189411/did-i-just-invent-a-bayesian-method-for-analysis-of-roc-curves

Comment: Thanks @GeneralAbrial . I read the post but I am not quite sure about it. So the Mann-Whitney U statistical test is the way to go?

Comment: The Mann-Whitney U statistic seems like a fairly straightforward statistical hypothesis test: $H_0$ the AUCs equal, $H_1$ they are unequal.

Comment: I am not sure if mann-whitney U statistics is the right one to go.

Comment: (several years late) this is closely related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/358101/statistical-significance-p-value-for-comparing-two-classifiers-with-respect-to/358598#358598

Answer (score 3):

DeLong (1988) proposed a statistical test for comparing two AUCs, which, like other hypothesis testing methods, depends on sample size and variance.

It was shown that the empirical AUC is equivalent to the Mann-Whitney two-sample statistic. This key insight allowed deriving the asymptotics of AUC and the statistical test.

For details,

1. DeLong, Elizabeth R., David M. DeLong, and Daniel L. Clarke-Pearson. "Comparing the areas under two or more correlated receiver operating characteristic curves: a nonparametric approach." Biometrics (1988): 837-845.
2. [NCSS software tutoria](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi4u6ae9-31AhVRl2oFHShKB2cQFnoECAsQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com%2Fwp-content%2Fthemes%2Fncss%2Fpdf%2FProcedures%2FNCSS%2FComparing_Two_ROC_Curves-Paired_Design.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2rYlsZJ5ck_wSw6Q5pNuTE)l

Answer (score 2):

Personally I suggest using a [randomized permutation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_(statistics)#Monte_Carlo_testing)

Area under curve (AUC) is just one test statistic. You have probably seen that the statistic of A is better than that of B. So it's already established that AUC of A is better than AUC of B. But what is not established is whether this superiority is due to systematic difference, or due to sheer dumb luck.

Therefore, now the question is: is the difference (regardless of which is better than the other) big enough to warrant assuming that the difference is due to systematic differences between methods A and B? In other words:

- What is the probability of you observing that A is better than B under the null hypothesis (which states that A and B have no systematic differences).

Generally, if you go with a [randomized permutation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_(statistics)#Monte_Carlo_testing), the procedure to estimate the probability above ($p$ value) is:

1. Calculate AUC of A vs. B (which I assume you already did).
2. Create C_1, such that C_1 is a pair-wisely randomly shuffled list of scores from A and B. In other words, C_1 is a simulation of what a random non-systematic difference looks like.
3. Measure AUC of C_1.
4. Test if AUC of C_1 is better than AUC of A. If yes, increment counter $damn$.
5. Repeat step 2 to 4 $n$ many times, but instead of C_1, use C_i where i $\in \{2, 3, \ldots, n\}$. Usually $n=1000$, but since it's asymptotically consistent, you are free to put larger values of $n$ if you have enough CPU time to go higher.
6. Then, $p = \frac{damn}{n}$.
7. If $p \le \alpha$, then the difference is significant. Usually $\alpha = 0.05$. Else: we don't know (maybe we need larger data).

Comment: Thanks! Several questions. (1) What the proper name for this method? (2) in step 2, what does is mean by "C_1 is a pair-wisely randomly shuffled list of scores from A and B. "? A and B are just a single value respectively.

Comment: (1) Approximate Randomization is what I learned this from. It seems that this is also called a randomized permutation test (as we find C_i that is a random permutation instead of exhaustive). (2) Sorry, some notation abuse here: A and B are method names, but here I used them as arrays. Arrays of what? Arrays of this: since you are doing AUC, you must be calculating the ROC curve, which means that you have the score (sensitivity/specificity) per threshold. So here I assumed that A and B are arrays of such sensitivity/specificity numbers, and C_i is just a randoml pairwise mix between A and B.

Comment: Thanks. Really, can I do that "since you are doing AUC, you must be calculating the ROC curve, which means that you have the score (sensitivity/specificity) per threshold. So here I assumed that A and B are arrays of such sensitivity/specificity numbers, and C_i is just a randoml pairwise mix between A and B." I do have such array (that how the ROC is formed), but the statistical test you mention is good for this kind of comparison?

Comment: Let's wait for gurus and hear their opinion. Feel free to invite them. Basically I've seen Approximate Randomization being used for measuring whether difference in accuracy between A and B is significant. But I havent' seen for AUC. I am not perfectly confident, but at the same time I can't see any reason why wouldn't it work for AUC as the method seems to not be specific to accuracy (as far as I have noticed). Either way let's wait for gurus.

Comment: Cool. Who is Gurus?

Comment: Gurus are the smart people here. Maybe General Abrial is one. Whuber and Glen_b are. I am sure there are much more. I'm new here so I don't know much people.

Comment: Ok! I hope he will see this and I am looking forward to it. How can I let him know about this questions